# Chrome app - load external content into div

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, load, google-chrome-app

I am writing a chrome app and I need to load the content of an online page into a div to use it.

Usually I use this code in online or local server but this doesn't work in app:

Jquery:

```
var contentURI= 'your-url #element';
$('#response').load('grab.php?
url='+ contentURI);
```

grab.php

```
<php echo file_get_contents
($_GET['url']); ?>
```

I also set the url of the site to load in permissions..

What can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XMLHttpRequest to read the page's data (or use $.Ajax) and then use the innerHTML property to set it as the div's content.